# How to get field of a class by its annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I created a simple annotation class:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Column {
    public String name();
}
```

I use it in some classes like this:

```
public class FgnPzt extends Point {

    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
    @Column(name=COLUMN_TYPE)
    protected String type;

}
```

I know that I can iterate over the declared fields and obtain the annotation like this:

```
for (Field field : current.getDeclaredFields()) {
    try {
        Column c = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        [...]
    } catch(Exception e) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

How can I obtain the field `type` directly by its annotated name without iterating over declared fields of the class?

Comment: Looking at the `Class` API, I would say that no, iterating over the fields is the only way. Is that a problem for you ?

Comment: I have classes with about twenty/thirty fields and I need to access to about all fields every time. If I iterate over each field every time, I will have a n*n complexity

Comment: You can use `field.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class);` for checking each field.

Comment: If you need to make multiple accesses you can pre-process the annotations. I'll post an answer

Comment: Yes, it's quite trivial to implement a simple "reflection cache" e.g. using a `ConcurrentHashMap` (or Guava cache).

Comment: @MickMnemonic in this way I need to iterate (that what I want to avoid)

Comment: according to the comments, you are asking wrong questions.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, you need to iterate, but is that _really_ a problem? You shouldn't optimize before you've identified a bottleneck. If the fields need to be accessed really frequently, then you can use a cache.

Comment: @Dici If I can't access directly, I think i have to change the algorithm policy

Comment: i mean its better to tell what you need to do and what you tried, instead of asking a specific thing that can be generally wrong. i didnt understand what you trying to achieve

Comment: @Lipsyor or you can *implement* this direct access. See my answer

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I need to set values of an object from a generic gui invoking standard set methods. There are no other specifics.

Comment: @Lipsyor ok. I saw the same task was solved by creating static "methodsCache" in each class. you can check the implementation here https://github.com/cuba-platform/cuba.  Classes to review - MethodsCache,  AbstractInstance #getValue #setValue methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to make multiple accesses you can pre-process the annotations.

```
public class ColumnExtracter<T> {
    private final Map<String, Field> fieldsByColumn;

    public ColumnExtracter(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.fieldsByColumn = Stream.of(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
              .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class))
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(field -> field.getAnnotation(Column.class).name(), Function.identity()));
    }

    public Field getColumnField(String columnName) {
        return fieldsByColumn.get(columnName);
    }

    public <R> R extract(String columnName, T t, Class<R> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException {
        return clazz.cast(extract(columnName, t));
    }

    public Object extract(String columnName, T t) throws IllegalAccessException {
        return getColumnField(columnName).get(t);
    }
}
```